# Definition of well-ordering and linear ordering?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, order-theory, well-orders

In my set theory notes, one definition is:

> Let $\langle A, < \rangle$ be a structure. $\langle A, < \rangle$ is a well-ordering if it is a well-founded linear ordering.

The problem is, nowhere in the notes does it mention what a linear ordering is. I can't find much online either so I wonder if it was meant to say "total ordering"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your guess is correct: "linear ordering" and "total ordering" are synonyms.